# Flutter web button size issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am creating a cross-platform app for both web and mobile. The buttons however have different default height depending on the platform. How can I make the height of the button to be the same size on both mobile and web without checking the platform?

Answer (score 12):

In my case, a button on the Web was noticeably smaller than on mobile. I was passing `padding` explicitly, but it was adjusted inside the Flutter framework.

Mobile (as intended):

[image: Mobile]

Web:

[image: Web]

The button code looks like this:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => RaisedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        color: color,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14, vertical: 8),
        child: child,
      );
```

I fixed the problem by setting `visualDensity` to `VisualDensity.standard` in `ThemeData` in `MaterialApp` initialization. For some reason, the default was `VisualDensity.compact`.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        // ...
        theme: ThemeData(
          // ...
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
        ),
        // ...
      );
}
```

Now size is as intended also on Web.

Answer (score 3):

with @cubuspl42 's answer,
the default `VisualDensity` of each platforms are like the follwoing.

```dart
  /// Returns a visual density that is adaptive based on the [defaultTargetPlatform].
  ///
  /// For desktop platforms, this returns [compact], and for other platforms,
  /// it returns a default-constructed [VisualDensity].
  static VisualDensity get adaptivePlatformDensity {
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
        break;
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return compact;
    }
    return VisualDensity.standard;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using material widget like RaisedButton, you can control the height as follows:

```
ButtonTheme(
  height: 100.0,
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Click here!"),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I guess 100.0 isn't the same on mobile and web. The button is significantly thinner on the web when setting the height to 100.

Comment: well, it depends on the pixel and resolution I guess.